# Moderator privileges with respect to IP addresses

Tags: support, moderators

Are site moderators able to view the IP addresses of people who have *viewed* a particular page?

Comment: I highly doubt that.

Answer (score 10):

Nope.

$\phantom{I am invisible text to make this answer get past the automatic filter. Thank goodness for mathjax}$

Comment: If you want to avoid MathJax, `&nbsp;` is six characters long.